# Startup Project with many software artifacts best practice 1 repo per artifact or start with one repo

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration

I'm having a tough time finding the right process in my dev project. I am developing a lot of things at once from lib utils (all in java) to many spring boot micro services and they all work together to create the runtime I deploy into Kubernetes.

Not all these artifacts are changed for each deployment, the problem is putting them all in their own repo at this point in the poject is cumbersome. Is it good practice to put all artifacts in a single repo when starting a large code base and then eventually break things out to their own repos which or just do that from the start?

Comment: Opinion: just do multiple repos from the start, you're not saving much time by starting with a monorepo.

Comment: I'm working at large corporation which I don't have the liberty of saying on this site but its a store we all visit often and they have gone mono repo and its a mess!